# Shibboleth - Secure whole IIS application

Tags: php, iis, iis-7.5, shibboleth, saml

I've setup `shibboleth SP` on my server and now I want to protect my IIS folders. I followed a few tutorials and used this syntax in my `shibboleth2.xml` file:

```
<RequestMapper type="Native">
     <RequestMap applicationId="default">
           <Host name="mydomain" redirectToSSL="443">
                <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" />
           </Host>
     </RequestMap>
</RequestMapper>
```

Now `mydomain.tld/secure` is protected by shibboleth which works fine.
How can I protect the root folder and every children in it?

I'm using a PHP application at the root of the webapp, also I'm using a few URLRewrite rules which redirect stuff like: `frontpage/item/123` to: `index.php?t=frontpage/item&id=123`.

How can I secure index.php and possibly all subfolders

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I got it myself. Basically you can add the `requireSession` attribute to the `Host` attribute, these are handled globally and the `Path` attributes are there to overwrite global behavior like disable shibboleth auth on `exception/` requests.

```
<RequestMapper type="Native">
     <RequestMap applicationId="default">
           <Host name="mydomain" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"  redirectToSSL="443">
                <Path name="exception" requireSession="false" />
           </Host>
     </RequestMap>
</RequestMapper>
```

Hope this helps other people as well. Correct me if I my explanation is wrong.